# Inheritance with Java constructor that uses Scanner

Tags: java, constructor, java.util.scanner

I'm an undergraduate that just started learning Java. This problem arises from an assignment which would be to create a Event Simulator, but I will be showing only the parts of the code I have an issue with, in particular the constructor.

I intend to do create a Queue object and a PriorityQueue object that inherits from the same Queue object, as I want to use the functions of the Queue Object. I intend to create them in a class called QueueManager, but the problem I have now is I want to use a Scanner in the constructor of the Queue(parent class), but I just want to create an empty PriorityQueue (child class) object without scanning.

The error message from the compiler

```
error: constructor Queue in class Queue cannot be applied to given types;
    public PriorityQueue(){
                          ^
  required: String[]
  found: no arguments
  reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length
```

What would be the way to do this, or is it even a good program design?

> Queue Manager

```
class QueueManager{
    private PriorityQueue p;
    private Queue q;

    public QueueManager(String [] args){
        this.q=new Queue(args);
        this.p=new PriorityQueue();
    }
```

> Queue

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class Queue{
    protected Event [] events =new Event [100];
    private int start=0;
    private int end=0;
    protected int size=0;
    private double time=0;


    public Queue(String [] args){
        Scanner s= new Scanner(System.in);
        int pos=0;
        while (s.hasNextDouble()){       
            double j=s.nextDouble();
            Event arrives=new Event("arrives",new Customer(j));
            this.events[pos]=arrives;
            pos++;
        }
        this.end=pos-1;
        this.size=pos;
    }
```

> PriorityQueue

```
class PriorityQueue extends Queue{
    private double totaltime=0;
    private int totalsize=0;

    public PriorityQueue(){
    };
```

PS: I came from a Python background and learnt some OOP over there(which seems abit rigged), without any emphasis on programming design practices. If anyone has some hard and fast rules for Java from Python and OOP programming design tips, feel free to share it. Thanks.

Comment: if you set the scanner in the parent class, it's also set for the child class, since it inherits the members of the parent class

Comment: your code is looking for a constructor you didn't define. designwise, first rule is don't cram unrelated things together. Queue shouldn't know about the Scanner. another flaw is [Constructor does real work](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwj5lY2k-ajdAhVI-6wKHQNDAxEQFjABegQICBAE&url=http%3A%2F%2Fmisko.hevery.com%2Fcode-reviewers-guide%2Fflaw-constructor-does-real-work%2F&usg=AOvVaw3-254D72x9zAB70T7G-VFo)

Comment: @NathanHughes actually I have an alternative to this problem, which is to create an array in QueueManager to get the input values, make both constructors receive arrays as arguments instead and pass in by reference. Sorry for the weird questions, but it doesn't come instinctively to me "Queue shouldn't know about the Scanner" as I'm not really familiar with programming practices.

Comment: Inheritance is explained pretty well in [oracles tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/subclasses.html) (generally quite a recommendable resource for the basics). Also have a look at the [separation of concerns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns)

Comment: I wouldn't read from the console in a constructor, I wouldn't use a `double` as a customer number.  I would make the Queue generic so it could handle any type of object. I would avoid using the name of a common, widely used class or interface to avoid confusion.

Comment: I wouldn't have a `size` or `totoalSize` but rather calcuate it from the start and the end.

Comment: Since PriorityQueue appears to use a different structure to Queue I would make them inherit a common abstract class or interface otherwise you are including stuff in the PriorityQueue which has no reason to be there.

Answer (score 1):

If you define a constructor that takes arguments, you don't get a no-ergument constructor for free anymore. So you're calling a constructor that isn't there, which is what the compiler is griping about.

Here you don't use the args passed into the Queue constructor, just delete the arguments from the constructor definition.  If you need both, then you have to define separate constructors, one that takes no arguments, and one that takes the String[] argument.

For separation of concerns: the stuff you have in your Queue constructor really belongs in a separate test harness script, it isn't specific to the Queue itself.

Comment: Do you mean that since I inherit from a class whose constructor takes in arguments, in Java(unlike Python), the super() will always be invoked regardless whether I write it for the subclass constructor. Since I wrote a non-empty argument constructor for my superclass, it overrides the old one unless I write explicitly another empty constructor for the super class to overload? Since the empty constructor of superclass wasn't found, that's why compiler throws a message.

Comment: @Prashin: yes, your PriorityQueue constructor needs to call a constructor for Queue. if you don't specify super(args) it will call the zero-arg constructor, which doesn't exist.